# Ceiling in only one room popping

Tags: ceiling, radiant-heating

My home is 38 years old. Brick. 1200 square feet with full basement. It has radiant ceiling heat but it is not the panel type. It was installed within the plaster. The ceiling in one room makes a lot of popping noise. A lot! No other room makes any sound at all.  I had blown insulation added about 3 years ago so I don’t think that’s the problem. My walls are not cracking anywhere. It’s my understanding that the radiant heat installed in the plaster is not a fire hazard. I love my heat. I can set every room to the temperature I want. Could the popping be from where this area is one with the heat set a little higher than the others?  I close off rooms I’m not using. This has been happening for the last couple years. Previously there was little to no noise.

Comment: I think "popping" could be anything from a hot-water pipe rubbing against a support as it expands and contracts to rodent activity to electrical issue; hard to tell which without actually hearing it. Can you correlate it to any particular time of day, or activity? Does it start when running hot water, or stop if you turn off the heating system (assuming hot-water heating)?

Comment: All my water pipes and hot water heater are in the basement. No signs of rodents anywhere.  I notice it more early morning and it often wakes me up at night. I don’t notice any difference when I turn the heat off in that room. Weather in Kentucky fluctuates a lot but I’d think if it was weather related I would hear it in all rooms.